# Difference between 'drawable' and 'drawable-v24' in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, directory, drawable, android-drawable

I am new to Android Studio and I was earlier using Eclipse.
I want to know difference between folders `drawable` and `drawable-v24` in Android Studio.

Comment: it's not a duplicate, the referred answer does not answer this question and is not as direct as this one(didn't know no-life reddit mods flooded here as well)

Answer (score 10):

The different drawable folders are for providing different screen densities for device compatibility and for different Android versions.

See this answer for more details:
[Newer versions of Android Studio and only two drawable directory - drawable and drawable-v21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343611/newer-versions-of-android-studio-and-only-two-drawable-directory-drawable-and)