# Application is not working other than Oreo

Tags: android, crash, version

I have created an app which is working fine on **Huawei Mate 10 Lite**,**Samsung S8** both are **Oreo version** and also on **emulator**.

But it's crashing on startup on other phones below **version 8**, showing this [error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bccz6d8vp4y0uti/error.txt?dl=0]). Here is my [manifest file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1669j9deqqi7vn9/AndroidManifest.xml?dl=0) and [app gradle](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wqidd046b9efd1e/gradle.txt?dl=0).

It is showing error on line 20 which is setContentView of SplashActivity.

```
`at incrementum.newsapp.activities.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:20)`
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    handler();
}
```

Help me I am about to upload on Appstore.

Comment: post the logcat error here

Comment: **android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "incrementum.newsapp:drawable/splash_screen"** check you have this in your drawable ?

Comment: @Quicklearner it's too long, I added an error link, kindly check it

Comment: seems like there is issue in your xml regarding drawable

Comment: we should not have to go off-site to see your code or logcat. Post **relevant part of it** here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the cause of your error

```
  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "incrementum.newsapp:drawable/splash_screen" (7f080081) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f080081 a=-1 r=0x7f080081}
```

I think your put your ressource inside a `drawable-v21` folder so if you use a lower version you need to put your drawable inside the `drawable` folder

Comment: You just need to rename your folder to drawable, or you can create it and put your drawable inside it

Answer (score 0):

It's probably same issue as this [Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095063/resourcesnotfoundexception-resource-is-not-a-drawable-color-or-path)  You're trying to use functionality that was only made available in Oreo and need to find a different way of doing it: [Newer versions of Android Studio and only two drawable directory - drawable and drawable-v21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343611/newer-versions-of-android-studio-and-only-two-drawable-directory-drawable-and)