# Navigation View Inflation error in android api 23

Tags: android, crash, navigationview

I updated my app and uploaded it to play store just to find out that it crashes on phones with Android api level 21-23 (my base api is 21) it works like a charm on Android 8.0 (complete error log at the bottom)

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.femindharamshi.spa/com.femindharamshi.spa.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML
>   file line #16: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

and

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16:
>   Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

So what might be causing this problem ? app opens, a white screen pops and it closes. On some phone is says  has stopped running while on the others no error message.

Here are some more references :

It shows the problem is caused on this line : `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

**My activity_main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**content_main.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/toolbarbackground" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_NavBarToggle"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="Menu Button"
            android:src="@drawable/menu" />

        <com.femindharamshi.spa.TextViewRegular
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/toolbar_title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="31sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/FrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </FrameLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
        <!--ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111 -->

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And my app level Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<package_name>"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 22
        versionName "v2.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.kbiakov:CodeView-android:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**a red line appears below** : `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

[image: A picture that shows this error]

**My app is an educational app and right now students have an exam so i need to rectify this problem as fast as possible. Any solutions ?**

Here is the complete error log :

```
    --------- beginning of crash
12-13 09:53:30.877 3881-3881/com.femindharamshi.spa E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.femindharamshi.spa, PID: 3881
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.femindharamshi.spa/com.femindharamshi.spa.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.femindharamshi.spa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:81)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.femindharamshi.spa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:81) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.femindharamshi.spa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:81) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070081
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1351)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:505)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:512)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:473)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:114)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:266)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:189)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:104)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at com.femindharamshi.spa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:81) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
12-13 09:53:30.882 1976-3173/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.femindharamshi.spa/.MainActivity
```

**EDIT:** @Nilesh Rathod found a the problem mentioned in the error logs. Some images were in drawable-v24 and not in drawable which was causing this problem.

Also to resolve the dependencies problem i included com.android.support:customtabs-28.0.0

Comment: Read the error  `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID` i guess one of your `drawable` image in `drawable-v24` not in `drawable`

Comment: Oh my god! a ic_menu_share.xml was created in drawable-v24 and that was causing the issue. Thanks alot. Life Saver xD

But can't api 23 and below use images in drawable-v24 ?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343611/newer-versions-of-android-studio-and-only-two-drawable-directory-drawable-and

Comment: @FeminDharamshi you can use you have to either add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in your .gradle file or make a work around to make it work

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. Thanks for the Information !