# Problem while adding an image in the background of a button

Tags: android, android-button

I am making a music player app. When I try to add an image in the background of the button a white background comes and no image is shown up.

Help me find my error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:background="@drawable/icons8-material-rounded-icons-96" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: see below image]

Comment: Use a imageButton instead

Comment: I have tried using that too. Still getting the same error.

Comment: what is the error

Comment: Use `ImageView` instead of `Button`

Comment: Did you run the app and see if it renders on your device, maybe the issue is with the layout editor.

Comment: Your issue in @drawable/icons8-material-rounded-icons-96 please check this

Comment: when u are copying your image to the drawable you were asked to move b/w two folders move to another folder which is not v24. It will solve the issue

Comment: Only a white background comes while inserting the image either using ImageButton or Button

Comment: Try my approach and let me know if it help you

Comment: @GOVINDDIXIT is right, please try to move the drawable(should not v-24) folder and it will be resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name of the image is not right ,when you build this project in gives error so please change image name **icons_material_rounded_icons_96** and then it will show background of button.it will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you are copying your image to the drawable you were asked to move between two folders move to another folder which is not v24.

**Steps:**

- Delete the image
- Again Copy the image to the drawable folder and this time choose the other folder which is not v24
  This will solve your issue

For more details check this answer [Newer versions of Android Studio and only two drawable directory - drawable and drawable-v21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343611/newer-versions-of-android-studio-and-only-two-drawable-directory-drawable-and)

Comment: Tried as you told. Nothing changed still the problem is coming.

Comment: Here is the link for the image of my screen. In-text view it shows that the image has been assigned to the button but when we preview no image is coming.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RAhTdXeX5yp7Bcv8RG8ZALxTdkOA2rxR

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an [Image button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton) if you want to show an image instead of text

```xml
<ImageButton
    android:src="@drawable/icons8-material-rounded-icons-96"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp" />
```

Also make sure you have moved the image to drawable folder as mentioned by @GOVIND DIXIT

Answer (score 0):

you can use ImageView

```
 <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dateClosure"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:background="@color/secondary_color"  
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:src="@drawable/calender2" />
```

background:- this is your background on which your image will be displayed.

src:- here put your image which will be displayed above your background