# Android appcompat button style not working

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-styles, android-appcompat

This is my base theme for application:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorSecondaryLight</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/NormalButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/NormalButtonStyle</item>
  </style>
```

And this is NormalButtonStyle:

```
  <style name="NormalButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/TitilliumWeb-SemiBold</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/progressBar</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorSecondaryLight</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorSecondaryLight</item>
  </style>
```

Here fontPath is attribute of [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library. But it is not working for me.

This is one of the AppCompatButton Code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btnLoginSignIn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/txt_sign_in"
    android:layout_below="@id/tilLoginPassword"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_top_margin_normal"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/tilLoginPassword"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/tilLoginPassword"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Android Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.astound.farmroster">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

  <application
      android:name=".app.MyApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarFullScreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Login"
        android:label="@string/txt_sign_in"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.Dashboard"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dashboard"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.JobList"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_job_list"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.JobDetail"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_job_detail"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you add AndroidManifest.xml  to your post?

Comment: Hey @fisher3421 I did

Comment: try with the file extension...`<item name="fontPath">fonts/TitilliumWeb-SemiBold.ttf</item>`

Comment: Thanks @rafsanahmad007 It worked. I just wanted to know one more thing:    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorSecondaryLight</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorSecondaryLight</item>  Which one is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Full file path with Extension:

instead of:

```
<item name="fontPath">fonts/TitilliumWeb-SemiBold</item>
```

use:

```
<item name="fontPath">fonts/TitilliumWeb-SemiBold.ttf</item>
```

Regarding your Second Question: Both are Right.

```
<item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorSecondaryLi‌​ght</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorSecondaryLight</ite‌​m>
```

Usage example

**theme.xml:**

```
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/button_color</item>
```

**v21/theme.xml**

```
<item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/button_color</item>
```

For More Help See this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519979/coloring-buttons-in-android-with-material-design-and-appcompat)

Answer (score 0):

add full file name to "fontPath" attribute in your style like:

```html
<item name="fontPath">fonts/TitilliumWeb-SemiBold.ttf</item>
```